# Root file listing: What's wrong with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls /data");?

Tags: android, root, ls

As you can see, I am building a simple Root explorer app with this code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!(requestRoot())) 
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Could Not Get Root!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Root Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    getDir("/");      //=>OK
    getDir("/data");  //=>NOT OK
    getDir("/data/"); //=>NOT OK
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Location: " + dirPath);

    item = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls "+dirPath);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            item.add(line);
            Log.e(dirPath, dirPath +" => "+ line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `getDir("/");` gives me all the expected results (a list of files including data) but `getDir("/data");` doesn't give any result or error...

Thank a lot for any clue on what is the problem.

EDIT:
I have also tried

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo ls /data");

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "ls /data/data"});
```